# Not able to render component using forEach in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, foreach, axios

I am creating a ReactJS Django application. In that i wanna display all the users whose data i get from the backend. I am using a loop to iterate through the list of users.

This is the Users.js from where im making the request using axios. And here im also using the forEach loop to populate the User.js component. I think this is where the problem is.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import User from "./User/User.js";

export default function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    document.querySelector("title").innerHTML = "Users | Recipe Book";
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:8000/users/")
            .then((response) => setUsers(response.data))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
    console.log("users component");
    return (
        <div className="container my-3">
            {users.forEach((user) => {
                console.log(user);
                return <User key={user.emailId} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

User.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function User(props) {
    console.log("User.js component.");
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="card">
                <Link>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        Use this kinda element to show user: {props}
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Just to verify that the component was imported and created properly, I even rendered it statically from outside the forEach loop. And it is working that way.

Please help me with this error which i have been facing for the past 3 days and I even tried using .map but then it is giving this error:

[image]

Comment: `users.forEach` -----> `users.map`

Comment: The  typeError is for your <Link> component that doesn't have a to={} property.

Comment: Because forEach return nothing. You should use map.

Comment: So.. forEach doesnt work in this case? Actually i used forEach for some other similar program and it worked over there.

Comment: Also i changed the question a little bit. now im getting a different error in .map()

Comment: Better show what the map looks like when you have the object there it is a problem of the way you are displaying it.